# What is the best way to sort strings with multiple words in each line and is separated by newline in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have list of anime that i have watch uptill now and i want to sort them in alphabetical order. Below is the small example of how the list is and there are over 200 lines. I have stored all of them in a text file. I am just asking for algorithm which can be used to sort this type of strings.

Also the names of anime are in Japanese so they can contain special character and numbers.

If it was just one word in each line then i could have easily used bucket sort or radix sort to do, but the problem is that there are multiple words in each line and those words shouldn't be sorted.

For example "Blue exorcist" should not be sorted or else it will become "exorcist Blue" or even the letters in it might also get sorted depending on algorithm you use.

```
One piece
Naruto/naruto shippuden
Bleach
Fullmetal alchemist brotherhood
Fate/stay night
Fairy tale
Blue exorcist
Soul eater
Death note
Code geass: lelouch of the rebellion r1 and r2
Gurren lagann
```

Here is my code

```
public static String[] ReadFileToCharArray (String filePath)
        throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder(1000);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String[] test = new String[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 105; i++)
    {
        test[i] = reader.readLine();

    }
    reader.close();
    return test;
}

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{

    String[] test = new String[10000];
    String path = "anime.txt";
    Files files = new Files();
    test = files.ReadFileToCharArray(path);
    Arrays.sort(test); // <----------ERROR at line 12
    System.out.println("test " + test);
    files.writetofiles(test);
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:232)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:176)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of problems with your code, eg unused fields (like fileData), hardcoded magic number (like 10000 and 105, which is probably why you are getting a NPE), etc

Comment: @tim I am experimenting with various methods so i had commented many lines of code but i forgot to comment variable initializations. Can you tell me what should i enter in place of 105?

Comment: take a look at the code I posted below. don't just run to any random number, but run up to the end of the file (until there are no more lines). the same with the array: don't just declare an array of random size, but one that has exactly enough space for all your lines (or use a list, which would be a lot easier).

Comment: @tim I manage to add new line but there is another problem output has "," and "[". Can you suggest me how to get rid of them?

Comment: if you want to replace something, use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29): `line = line.replace(",", "");`

Comment: @tim Not working. There are no "," and "[" in the input files. They are only present in output files.

Comment: My guess would be that you are just printing the list directly, not iterating over it and printing each entry. and when java displays a list (via `toString`, it does it like this: `[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that there are multiple words in each line and those words shouldn't be sorted.

If I understand you correctly, you could just read the file line by line (instead of word by word):

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    names.add(line);
}
br.close();

Collections.sort(names);
// TODO write names to file
```

If you're using Linux, you could also just use `sort`:

```bash
sort fileName > fileNameSorted
```

Comment: @user3933143 see my comment above. and which inbuild function do you mean? `Collections.sort`? just choose any sort algorithm that can sort strings and implement that.

Comment: It worked. Thank you sir. Just one last question. Can you tell me how to add new line. In this case entire files is written in continuous order.

Comment: @user3933143 depends how you are writing the names to a file. I'm guessing you are iterating over them and adding them entry by entry? just append "\n" (newline) after each line